# How to save the value of a variable converted to base64?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a .zip file with thousands of geographical coordinates and converting to base64.

I can convert the file to base64, the problem is to save the result of this variable for later use.

I'm trying to use `setState` to save the variable's value but nothing happens.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code I put in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-christian-22ki1?file=/src/App.js)

And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U55pbTW8RBqKxCj6bQboGhOMiE0Yn15I/view) the zilFile I'm converting

```js
  const [zipFile, setZipFile] = useState("");
  const [base64, setBase64] = useState("");

  const getBase64 = (file, cb) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
      cb(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {};
  };

  const toBase64 = async () => {
    let auxZip = "";
    await getBase64(zipFile, (result) => {
      auxZip = result.substring(28);
      console.log("auxZip: ", auxZip);
      setBase64(auxZip);
    });
  };

  const onSave = () => {
    toBase64();

    console.log("base64: ", base64);
  };

  const handleZipChangle = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setZipFile(file);
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed like this, it worked perfectly, please take a look.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function App() {
  const [base64, setBase64] = useState("");

  const getBase64 = (file, cb) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
      cb(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {};
  };

  const onSave = () => {
    console.log("base64: ", base64);
  };

  const handleZipChangle = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    let auxZip = "";
    getBase64(file, (result) => {
      auxZip = result.substring(28);
      setBase64(auxZip);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormControl>
        <Typography>Select Zip File:</Typography>
        <input
          accept="zip/*"
          type="file"
          id="contained-button-file"
          onChange={handleZipChangle}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
        <button onClick={onSave}>SAVE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or if you want to use zip file, you can use useEffect to check the state loaded and call `getBase64`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let auxZip = "";
    zipFile &&
      getBase64(zipFile, (result) => {
        auxZip = result.substring(28);
        setBase64(auxZip);
      });
  }, [zipFile]);

  const onSave = () => {
    console.log("base64: ", base64);
  };

  const handleZipChangle = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setZipFile(file);
  };
```

Comment: Hey Cuong, thank you, but Even making the change you indicated, it remains the same as the image.

Comment: hmm, I have tested, it's okay

Comment: When I look at the variable's `base64 ` value outside of `onSave()`, the variable's value is filled, but inside `onSave()` it remains empty.

Comment: using like this:    await toBase64();

Comment: const onSave = () => {
    toBase64();

    console.log("base64: ", base64);
  };

Comment: or like this. it will be okay

Comment: I have changed my answer, please take a look

Comment: Hey Cuong, I dont' use async await anymore, take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-christian-22ki1?file=/src/App.js:723-730, `base64` still empty inside `onSave()` "/

Comment: sorry, I did not watched closely the console! I have edited, it works perfectly.

Comment: Hey Cuong, that´s works perfectly for me, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `auxZip` has been set. Cause function `toBase64` is async, the `auxZip` is empty.

You can check by:

```
  const toBase64 = async () => {
    let auxZip = "";
    getBase64(zipFile, (result) => {
      auxZip = result.substring(28);
      // console.log("auxZip: ", auxZip);
      setBase64(auxZip);
    });
  };

  console.log(base64);

  const onSave = async () => {
    await toBase64();

    console.log("base64: ", base64);
  };
```

Comment: Hey Vie, thank you, but Even making the change you indicated, it remains the same as the image.